# Getting "xprop: unable to open display" while sending an email in the docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rubygems

I am using a gem 'letter_opener_web' in our application.

When we are running a script and trying to send an email at that time, we are getting the following error in the console.

```
xprop:  unable to open display ''

xprop:  unable to open display ''

xdg-open /.../tmp/letter_opener/1708508975_9987023_e9d40c9/rich.html
```

It does not affect the existing functionality. But we are getting the above text message on the console.

Note: This issue we are getting while the application running in the docker.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547192/running-xprop-in-a-crontab-unable-to-open-display, the main cause of this error that docker doesn't have an X11 session.

Also, please read [Usage](https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web?tab=readme-ov-file#usage) of this gem. There is instruction on how to fix similar errors.